# Storing information through multiple iterations

Tags: node.js, json, object

Hey there so I'm pretty new to coding, I've been learning JavaScript for about a month now. I've created a very basic password generator just to test everything I've learnt, however I'm trying to figure out how I'd be able to store these passwords through another script in Node.js. I'm currently at the barest of bones with the storage part, creating an object with an empty ID and the password variable however I'm unsure how to write the code to let the script create multiple objects to store these passwords. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Store them where?

Comment: Questions about code here get faster and more accurate answers when they aren't theoretical, but rather you include the relevant portions of your code as text in the question (formatted as code, not as a screenshot) and then ask a specific question about that code.

Comment: There are lots of ways to store things from nodejs.  You can put stuff in a database.  You can put it in an array and using `JSON.stringify()` to convert it to JSON and then use `fs.writeFile()` to write that JSON string to disk.  You can create your own .CSV file format and write that format of text to disk.  You can create your own binary data format and write that to disk.  You can use a cloud-based storage system and their APIs to store stuff in the cloud and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Since he mentioned being new to JS and coding in general, I think I can safely assume OP doesn't want anything fancy and just store the password(s) he generated, no matter where.

There are many possibilities when it comes to storing things.

A good place to start would be to look for storing them [in a file](https://nodejs.dev/learn/writing-files-with-nodejs) first.

```
const fs = require('fs');

// say this is your passwords object
const passwds = myFunctionGeneratingPassword();

// a file 'passwords.json' will be created in your current working directory
const pathToFile = 'passwords.json';
try {
  fs.writeFileSync(pathToFile, content)
  //file written successfully
} catch (err) {
  // if any error with the writing should occur, the error must be handled here
  console.error(err)
}
```

Of course, you would also want to [read](https://nodejs.dev/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs) them:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// the same file you created in the step before
const pathToFile = 'passwords.json';

try {
  const data = fs.readFileSync(pathToFile, 'utf8');
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(parsedData);
} catch (err) {
  // if any error with the reading should occur, the error must be handled here
  console.error(err)
}
```

Now, you could also store them in a database such as [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) (there are many others, MongoDB just happens to work well in general with JS stacks), or any other kind of file as jfriend00 mentioned in the comments as I was writing this, but I think you'll need to fiddle a bit more with JS before diving into these subjects.